# Update apart of row in sql by prepared statements

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I got a product table with id, name, description, color, price, quantity and status

How I can update only the name, description or just 2-3 fields in a row by using prepared statements. For example, my prepared statement is

`UPDATE product SET product_name = ?, product_desc = ?,product_size = ?, product_color = ?,product_price = ?,product_quantity = ?, product_status = ? WHERE id = $id`

and the `bind_param` looks like this

`bind_param("ssssiii", $data['name'], $data['desc'], $data['size'], $data['color'], $data['price'], $data['quantity'], $data['status'])`

and supposed that the `$data['color']` and `$data['quantity']` is empty then how can I update that row in the database to retain the old value of `product_color` and `product_quantity` columns.

Does it automatically keep old data when executing an update statement or I had to do some validation of something like that?

here is my code:

```
        $connect = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);;
        $sql = "UPDATE product SET product_name = ?, product_desc = ?,product_size = ?,
                product_color = ?,product_price = ?,product_quantity = ?, product_status = ? 
                WHERE id = $id";

        $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bind_param("ssssiii", $data['name'], $data['desc'], $data['size'], $data['color'],
                        $data['price'],$data['quantity'],$data['status']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
```

Comment: you need to ensure that all fields are populated, filtration validation before any query

Comment: Just `SET ` the columns you want to UPDATE, you dont have to do all of them, its not like an INSERT

Comment: `WHERE id = $id` < why did you stop there? You're still open to injection.

Comment: `UPDATE $tableName` < that looks dangerous and is open to a major injection.

Comment: Yes you can use an IF and it will not slow things down in any amount you can calulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
UPDATE $tableName
    SET product_name = COALESCE(?, product_name),
        product_desc = COALESCE(?, product_desc),
        product_size = COALESCE(?, product_size),
        product_color = COALESCE(?, product_color),
        product_quantity = COALESCE(?, product_quantity),
        product_status = COALESCE(?, product_status)
    WHERE id = ?;
```

Notes:

- This assumes that the passed in parameters are `NULL` when you don't want the values set.
- You cannot set a column to `NULL`.
- I changed the `WHERE` so it references a parameter.